# Epilog->Inset crops text with large font sizes

Tags: graphics

Why does `Epilog->Inset` crop the first and last letters here ("a" and "g") when `FontSize` is set to large values (which varies with font family):

```
Plot[Cos[t], {t, -32 Pi, 32 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1/4, PlotRange -> All,
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Graphics@
    Text[Style["a   b   c   d   e   f   g", FontSize -> 30]], {0, 0}]
 ]
```

This renders as:

[image]

Are there options or a hack which still uses `Epilog -> Inset`, as opposed to using `Show` and passing the text as `Graphics` (which works correctly)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove `Graphics` inside `Inset`:

```
 Plot[Cos[t], {t, -32 Pi, 32 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1/4, PlotRange -> All,
 Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Text[Style["a b c d e f g", FontSize -> 60]], {0, 0}]]
```

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to @Brett's comment, the following `Epilog` settings also work:

```
Inset[Style["a b c d e f g", FontSize -> 60], {0, 0}]
(* or *) Text[Style["a b c d e f g", FontSize -> 60], {0, 0}]
(* or *) Style[Text["a b c d e f g", {0, 0}], FontSize -> 60]
```

Comment: Got it thanks. 2nd question (after removing Graphics) if pos is changed to {0,-1} or lower, the text gets cropped. Any ideas?

Comment: @alancalvitti I've addressed this question in the answer I posted. For your case kguler's answer works fine (+1), but you shouldn't think that `Graphics` is in any way forbidden inside `Inset`.

Comment: You could just use `Inset[Style[...], {0,0}]` or even `Text[Style[...], {0,0}]` since `Text` as a graphics primitive is implemented using `Inset` these days.

Comment: Alan, thanks for the accept. As @Jens explains in his answer, `PlotRangePadding` is the solution to avoid cropping of inset objects. Jens, thank you for the vote.

Comment: @Brett, added your suggestions to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Here are two possibilities to make the `Inset` work in exactly the form you have it right now:

- Use the scale argument for `Inset` and set it to `Scaled[1]`
- Use the `ImageSize` option for the inset `Graphics` and set it to `Full`

Both have essentially the same effect of asking the inset object to fill out the *enclosing* graphic fully. Since `Text` doesn't usually resize, it only has the effect of removing any cropping around the text, as desired. You could also just specify a fixed but sufficiently large `ImageSize` in the inset `Graphics` but that would require manual adjustment.

Here is how you'd do that for the example:

```
Plot[Cos[t], {t, -32 Pi, 32 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1/4, PlotRange -> All,
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Graphics@
    Text[Style["a   b   c   d   e   f   g", FontSize -> 30]], {0, 0}, 
   Automatic, Scaled[1]]]

Plot[Cos[t], {t, -32 Pi, 32 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1/4, PlotRange -> All,
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Graphics[
    Text[Style["a   b   c   d   e   f   g", FontSize -> 30]], 
    ImageSize -> Full], {0, 0}]]
```

You then can get additional cropping problems when the `Inset` position is moved too far down (or anywhere beyond the plot range). This is a different issue and can be resolved by *either* specifying a `PlotRange` that's larger than `All`, or (to be independent of the specific range) by adding the option `PlotRangePadding`:

```
Plot[Cos[t], {t, -32 Pi, 32 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1/4, 
 PlotRange -> All,
 Axes -> True,
 ImageSize -> 600,
 (*  added padding to accomodate inset: *)
 PlotRangePadding -> .5,
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Graphics[
    Text[Style["a   b   c   d   e   f   g", 
      FontSize -> 30]]], {0, -1}, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]
```

[image: inset]