# Using Epilog to increase text size

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a plot with labels positioned using the epilog function for convenience. I would like to increase the size of axes labels within the epilog function but I haven't managed to figure out a way to do so. I've read through a number of posts ([post_1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7956/epilog-inset-crops-text-with-large-font-sizes), [post_2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29597/epilog-text-placement-on-loglogplot)) but they all don't seem to address this problem. My codes are given below:

```
Plot[x^2 + 4 x, {x, -7, 6}, ImageSize -> 600,  
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.03}], 
Epilog -> { Inset["x axis", Scaled[{0.5, 0.15}]], 
Inset["y axis", Scaled[{0.5, 0.95}]]}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium]]
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `Style` on the argument of `Inset` to impose a style on the text labels: e.g. `Style["x axis", FontSize -> 25]`

Comment: Thanks so much. Took a while to figure that one out. I'll post the solution below my question.

Comment: John, glad to help. Answering your own question is highly encouraged here on stackexchange. Rather than adding the answer directly to the question, would you please post the solution as your own answer? That will make the question show up as answered to other people with a similar problem.

Comment: Great, I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Thanks to MarcoB, here's the solution (this increases the size of the x axis label):

```
Plot[x^2 + 4 x, {x, -7, 6}, ImageSize -> 600,  
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.03}], 
Epilog -> { 
Inset[Style["x axis", FontSize -> 25], Scaled[{0.5, 0.15}]], 
Inset["y axis", Scaled[{0.5, 0.95}]]}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium]]
```